# Copy a Folder and Create a Jar in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a task to copy a folder and create a jar. used maven-assembly plugin to generate a jar but the problem is its creates a Folder with artificat-id + Version i dont want to create i need as is what i copied and create a jar.

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>concordian</id> 
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <!-- Adds the dependencies of our application -->

    <fileSets>
        <!-- Adds deploy scripts to the root directory of zip package. -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/concordion</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

it ends up in creating jar with folder + and whatever the file i copied from above structure. i need to remove the Folder +

Comment: Why are you trying to create a jar via maven-assmbly-plugin instead of maven-jar-plugin?

Comment: I am allready creating a Jar but i need to create one more jar with some file.

Comment: What do you mean by `with some files` ?  What about the includes option of maven-jar-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by different ways, with the `maven-assembly-plugin` or with the `maven-jar-plugin` :

1. With the `maven-assembly-plugin` you have to declare the execution of the plugin in the pom and create your assembly file like this, you don't need to touch the configuration of the `maven-jar-plugin` (except for other reasons) :

In the **pom.xml** :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-plus</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/jar-plus.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here I put the assembly in the folder `src/assembly`, and I call it `jar-plus.xml`.

Assembly jar-plus.xml :

```xml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>jar-plus</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>src/additionnal-folder</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I put just one additionnal folder but you can configure as many as you want and set includes and excludes.

2. With the `maven-jar-plugin` you have to make two executions of the plugin :

A first execution to generate the jar that will be the biggest one with all the resources defined with the `maven-resources-plugin`. And a second execution for the smallest jar in which you will describe all the excludes in order to avoid the files you don't want to have in the smallest jar (I added classifiers in my sample code bellow to make the difference between the two jars but you can avoid adding a classifier for the "normal" jar).

In the **pom.xml** :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>biggest-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>biggest</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>normal-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>normal</classifier>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*exclude-file*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```