# Jar executable of spring app file upload failed?

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, jar

This spring app performs simple file upload,

here's the controller class

```
    @Override
        public String fileUpload(MultipartFile file) {
    
            try{
                
                // save uploaded image to images folder in root dir
                Files.write(Paths.get("images/"+ file.getOriginalFilename()), file.getBytes());
                
                // perform some tasks on image 
                return "";
    
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                
                return "File upload has failed.";
            } finally {
                Files.delete(Paths.get("images/" + file.getOriginalFilename()));
            }
        }
```

but when i build jar and runs, it throws IOException saying,
`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: images\8c9.jpeg`.

So my question is how can i add the images folder inside the jar executable itself.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a directory 'images' at the same place where your executable jar is ? or maybe you need to set a full path

Comment: @guchuan, ah yes but can i add that folder inside the jar itself ?

Comment: how does your source code project look like ? you can try "classpath:images/..." if it's somewhere under classpath resources

Comment: images directory is in the root directory of the project

Comment: how is it included in your jar file ? can you change it to be placed under your classpath resource like 'src/main/resources' ?

Comment: @guchuan, i think its not that's what im asking how ? i searched few blogs and tried its not works well

Comment: my bad, so you wanted to know how to build a jar with your images dir inside it. well it depends what you're using to build it. are you using maven ? gradle?

Comment: @guchuan yes, would you please post an answer ?

Comment: can this be your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470153/copy-a-folder-and-create-a-jar-in-maven

Comment: The "inside of the jar" _is not writeable_. You need to store your images externally; common options include a network share on a file server, stuffing them in a database, or using an object store like S3.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- what about storing it like this `new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))`

Comment: That will, of course, _work_ just fine for a trial, but keep in mind that (1) the temporary directory likely has limited space and (2) it's temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a full path for the images folder, or save in `java.io.tmpdir` creating the image folder first.

But, in my opinion you should configure your upload folder from a config file for flexibility. Take a look at this.

```
app:
   profile-image:
      upload-dir: C:\\projs\\web\\profile_image
      file-types: jpg, JPG, png, PNG
      width-height: 360, 360
      max-size: 5242880
```

In your service or controller, do whatever you like, may be **validate** image type, size etc and process it as you like. For instance, if you want thumbnails(or avatar..).

In your controller or service class, get the directory:

```
@Value("${app.image-upload-dir:../images}")
private String imageUploadDir;
```

Finally,

```
public static Path uploadFileToPath(String fullFileName, String uploadDir, byte[] filecontent) throws IOException {
    Path fileOut = null;
    try{
        Path fileAbsolutePath = Paths.get(StringUtils.join(uploadDir, File.separatorChar, fullFileName));
        fileOut = Files.write(fileAbsolutePath, filecontent);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return fileOut; //full path of the file
}
```

**For your question in the comment:** You can use `java.io.File.deleteOnExit()` method, which deletes the file or directory defined by the abstract path name when the virtual machine *terminates*. TAKE A GOOD CARE THOUGH, it might leave some files if not handled properly.

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();){
    URL fileUrl = new URL(url);
    String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    String path = tempDir + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"; // note file extension 
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(path); 
    file.deleteOnExit();
    
    inputStream = fileUrl.openStream();
    ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, output); // ByteStreams - Guava
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    output.writeTo(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    return file;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    try {
    if(inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if(outputStream != null) {
        outputStream.close();
    }
    } catch(Exception e){
        //skip
    }
}
```

Comment: is it okay to delete file after processing it, inside finally block

Comment: What do you mean by processing? If you don;t need it, why download it? If the file is not too large, read its content to byte buffer

Comment: ohh... this is for OCR thing once the text is extracted image should be deleted,